# How to select between different PLL and divider configurations with same result

Tags: stm32, clock, pll, frequency-divider

I'm new to STM32 and totally ARM. I'm learning STM32 by a NUCLEO-L053R8 board and currently working on clock configurations.

I want to clock CPU, USB and RNG all by PLL connected to HSI16 so there is no need to HSI48 which saves some power. I can use two configurations:
[image: CFG0]

[image: CFG1]

What's the difference between these two configurations?

Comment: PLL stands for phase-locked loop, in microcontroller mostly used to multiply the frequency value by a determined coefficient. Shortly It won't create any difference in your application.

Comment: @emreiris Thanks for explanation. By difference I mean power consumption, clock stability, etc.

Comment: Even if both configurations are possible and result into same output frequency, the datasheet will tell you what is the optimum range for jitter or stability. You can then try measuring for any difference in current consumption.